# Drop table with condition - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to drop the table with condition?

For example:

`DROP table table_name where (select column from table) = (select column from table2)`

NOTE : Without PLSQL

Comment: Yes, but using dynamic SQL or PL/SQL rather than just `DROP TABLE`.  Your question is unclear.  The answer is "no drop table doesn't do this".  But presumably you want the code that does do that -- although you haven't asked that question.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't add where in [drop table statement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9003.htm)

[image]

You will get error `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible.

Please read the Oracle documentation:

[Oracle Drop Table](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/DROP-TABLE.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest option here would be to gather drop table statements using your conditions into a sort of script

```
select listagg('drop table ' || owner || '.' || table_name || ';', ' ') within group(order by 1) from all_tables where <your_condition>
```

and then execute it